# Scroll Section to top when active trigger in ScrollMagic

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

I try use Scrolltomagic to scroll section when trigger is activated.

```
var sceneOptions2 = {duration: 500};
var divfocus = $("div.wrapper section");
```

when the section is activated it should go up to the top of the page. 
But scrolling donts works.

```
new ScrollScene(sceneOptions2)
.addTo(controller)
.triggerHook("onCenter")
.triggerElement(divfocus[1])
.setTween(TweenMax.to(divfocus[1], 2, {scrollTo:{y:50}, ease:Back.easeOut}));
```

How can make the section go to top when it is activated by the trigger?

complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/14ktjsb7/4/

---

*ps: Any suggestion for optmize my code, maybe a clean way*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollMagic is a scroll interaction plugin, not a scroll jacking plugin.
To force breaks in scroll position use [fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) or [OnePageScroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html).

Full answer here: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/234